# ¿Me pueden explicar que significa "paises.listIterator()"?

Tags: java

```
package colecciones;

import java.util.*;

public class PaisesCapital {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LinkedList<String> paises=new LinkedList<String>();

        paises.add("España");

        paises.add("Colombia");

        paises.add("Mexico");

        paises.add("Peru");

        LinkedList<String> capitales=new LinkedList<String>();

        capitales.add("Madrid");

        capitales.add("Bogota");

        capitales.add("Mexico DF");

        capitales.add("Lima");

        ListIterator<String> iteP=paises.listIterator();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te aconsejo revisar siempre la documentación,

> El método [listIterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator--) Devuelve un iterador de lista sobre los elementos de esta lista (en la secuencia adecuada).

Un iterador es un objeto que nos permite recorrer una lista, para realizar esta operación se hace uso de los métodos [hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--) y [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--).

Al obtener esta lista puedes iterar sobre la misma para obtener los elementos, por ejemplo:

```
    LinkedList<String> paises=new LinkedList<String>();
    paises.add("España");
    paises.add("Colombia");
    paises.add("Mexico");
    paises.add("Peru");
    ListIterator<String> iteP=paises.listIterator();

    while(iteP.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(iteP.next());         
    }
```

La salida sería:

```
España
Colombia
Mexico
Peru
```

Answer (score 1):

Un iterador es una manera eficiente de recorrer una colección. Su complejidad es lineal. Utiliza otros métodos para recorrer las listas. El método hasNext() se usa para iterar en la lista (mientras haya siguiente elemento), y el next() se usa para coger el valor de la lista.

Comment: Si un iterador fuera una manera eficiente, entonces quiere decir que hay maneras ineficientes? A tu respuesta suena a que le falta algo. revias [answer]